# Shell_exec php with nohup

Tags: php, exec, shellexecute, shell-exec, nohup

I think there are tons of similar posts but I haven't yet found a solution after searching around.

Basically, I'm trying to run two scripts in the background. When I run them in the commandline, I see after calling my first script:

```
/usr/bin/nohup php script.php > nohupoutput.log & echo $!
```

I've tried  `...script.php > /dev/null &` with the same result. I get:

```
/usr/bin/nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
```

which I ignore and run the second one. I noticed that it seemed to be hanging there, and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> brought me back to `machine:~folder>`

```
/usr/bin/nohup php script2.php > nohupoutput.log & echo $!
```

Both scripts work. I tried to then convert this to a shell_exec command and nothing seems to work. I suspect that the `ignoring input` bit is causing difficulties, but I'm not sure. Regardless, the following does not work. It just hangs in the browser:

```
$output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/nohup php script.php > /dev/null &');
$output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/nohup php script2.php > /dev/null &');
```

Answer (score 12):

Try:

```
$output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/nohup php script.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

Or:

```
exec('/usr/bin/nohup php script.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

Comment: I'm getting a Ambiguous output redirect when I try both on the command line.

Comment: which os are you using, and php version? this is a odd one.

Answer (score 2):

This shoul work:

```
shell_exec('nohup /usr/bin/php path/to/script.php > output.txt &');
```

Answer (score 2):

```php
<?php
function execInBackground($cmd) {
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r")); 
    }
    else {
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");  
    }
}

// take note: to get your PHP_PATH, try looking at your phpinfo :)
echo execInBackground("/usr/local/php53/bin/php 'example2.php'");
?>
```

Comment: `popen('nohup ... &', 'r')` is the only method that is working for me in OS X as well as Heroku. A ton of other solutions for running detached background processes incl. Symfony, Cocur, et al failed (either blocked execution or would die when parent dies).

Answer (score 0):

First put your php command in a shell file script, e.g. **myscript.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
# myscript.sh file
php script.php
```

Run nohup with myscript.sh:

```
sudo nohup ./myscript.sh &
```

Verify with ps:

```
ps aux | grep myscript.sh
```