# executed nohup command over php gets terminated

Tags: php, jquery, nohup

I have an php file named gg.php:

```
<?php
exec('nohup ~/www/htdocs/w00daffe/gogs/packs/src/github.com/gogits/gogs/gogs web >/dev/null 2>&1 &');
exit();
?>
```

What i want to do, is that the go script runs even if i quit. This command works fine over ssh and runs even after i exit out of CLI. It should execute that script and it should run after it. I am really confused. I execute it over JQuery with AJAX:

```
$.get("gg.php");
```

Thanks in Advance :)

EDIT:
It doesnt work, if i delete exit();

Comment: does it work when you remove the `exit();`?

Comment: No, unfortunately not

Comment: Have you tried what is explained in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929827/shell-exec-php-with-nohup and is there a reason you call exit()? isn't the php script done anyway?

Comment: Oh, i forgot the last '&'. Thanks!