# Cannot kill a process by a PHP Script running behind nohup

Tags: php, linux, nohup

I have a php script that perform some actions after killing some old processes.

`act.php`

```
$pids = shell_exec('ps aux | grep "saso" | awk \'{print $2}\'');
$pids = str_replace("\n", ' ', $pids);
$pids = array_filter(explode(' ', $pids));

foreach ($pids as $pid) {
    shell_exec('kill -9 ' . $pid . ' > /dev/null 2>&1 &');
}

// reset of the code . ..
```

The script works well by running `php act.php`. It fetch process ids, kill it, then run the rest.

But it is not working when I run `nohup php act.php &` or `nohup php act.php`. The process is not killed.

I need `nohup` to run the script in the background with no hang up.

Can't PHP script fetch pids behind `nohup` ? and are there any alternatives ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

If you search properly, you can find the [result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929827/shell-exec-php-with-nohup).

Try:

```
$output = shell_exec('/usr/bin/nohup php script.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

Or:

```
exec('/usr/bin/nohup php script.php >/dev/null 2>&1 &');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I see. The idea is: `nohup` cannot get `pids`, It always return empty list, However if I run the script without `nohup` EX: `php script.php` it gets the `pids` well.